# How to implement this piece of code so it checks the tags and changes it

Tags: php, twitter

Englisch isn't  my nativa languages so I am sorry for any grammar mistakes. The piece of code below working fine. I am making a  blog so you can write things online. I have working code that can change # into a link to twitter. But I can't get it working that it will use $tags to change the words it gets from my database to twitterlinks. I will paste the working twitter code below. Who can help me? I am still learning PHP so I am sorry for any mistakes made by me. If you need more info to help me please comment and I will as best as I can to provide you with information.

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Overzicht alle Blogs</h1><br><br>
<a href="admin.php" class="klick3">Voeg een blog toe !</a>
<p id="klick2">⇓</p>
<br><br><br>
<?php
//hier includen we de benodigde bestanden.
include_once("connection.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $dbCon->query($query);

// hier fetchen we de benodige onderdelen voor een blog.
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$title = $row['title'];
$subtitle = $row['subtitle'];
$content = $row['content'];  
$datums = $row['datums'];
$gebruiker_id = $row['gebruiker_id'];
$user_name = $row['user_name'];
$tags = $row['tags'];
//print_r($row);
?>
<?php
$rest = substr($content, 0, 800). ".....";  
?>   
<div class="blogss">
     <h2><?php echo htmlentities($title); ?> - <small><?php echo         htmlentities($subtitle); ?></small></h2>
    <p><?php echo htmlentities($rest); ?></p>
    <?php
    //$testlees = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    ?>
    <a href="blog.com?id=<?php echo $testlees; ?>" class="lees">Lees meer</a> 
    <p class="datumss"><?php echo $datums;?> </p>
    <p class="tags">Tags: <?php echo $tags; ?></p>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<?php
 }
 ?>
 <br />
```

This is the working code that I tested on an empty index.php page. It changes the words I put # in front of to a  twitter hyperlink. I tested in a echo and it worked. working code for twitter can be found below.

```
  // Get all hashtags out into an array
  if (preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(#\w+)/', $test, $arrHashtags) > 0) {
  foreach ($arrHashtags[2] as $strHashtag) {
// Check each tag to see if there are letters or an underscore in there somewhere
if (preg_match('/#\d*[a-z_]+/i', $strHashtag)) {
  $test = str_replace($strHashtag, '<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%40'.substr($strHashtag, 1).'">'.$strHashtag.'</a>', $test);
     }
   }
}

     echo $test;
     ?>
```

Comment: I think what you want is to split the tags into an array using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) after which you can loop through that array using a `foreach` construct.

Comment: I already solved it but putting the code before I echo $tags. I changed $test to $tags and now it works.